# Is there a transformation that satisfies $f(Ax+By)=x+y$ where $x$, $y$ are vectors and $A$, $B$ are matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given $x, y$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $A$, $B$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, is there a transformation $f :\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ that satisfies $$f(Ax+By)=x+y\ ?$$

Comment: Such a map need not be well-defined. Take $A=B=0$. Then $f(0)=f(0x+0y)=x+y$ for all $x,y$, so $f(0)$ has no well-defined value.

Comment: Even if $A$ and $B$ are invertible $f$ need not exist. In fact, $f(Ax)=x$ so $f(x)=A^{-1}x$ and we also have $f(y)=B^{-1}(y)$ so we need $A=B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off the comments, the necessary and sufficient condition for $f$ to exist is that $A=B$ and $A$ is invertible, in which case $f(x) = A^{-1}x$ works.

If $A$ is not invertible, pick $v \ne 0$ such that $Av = 0.$ Letting $(x,y)=(v,0), (0,0),$ we get $v = f(Av+B0)=f(0v+B0) = 0,$ contradiction. Similarly, $B$ must be invertible.

Now letting $y = 0$ gives $f(Ax) = x \Rightarrow f(x) = A^{-1}x,$ while letting $x = 0$ gives $f(y) = B^{-1}y,$ so $A^{-1}v=B^{-1}v$ for all $v,$ implying $A^{-1} = B^{-1} \Rightarrow A=B.$